# What is the best way to load HTML content based on device?

Tags: html, css

I have two different div element (one for desktop and other for mobile) which have to be loaded based on the device accessing my website. What is the best way to do this? I do not want to check the user agent since it gets updated often.

Right now I'm using css media queries to find the device specs and hide / show the corresponding div. The problem is, I'm loading both the divs irrespective of the device. I only want to load the corresponding div.

Furthermore, re-sizing the desktop browser to the size of mobile should load the mobile div. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't load the corresponding div if you don't know what device are seeing the web... (you only can know this using user agent or some library like http://mobiledetect.net/  Show and hide with medie queries maybe a good option. (In my opinion)

Comment: Is is possible to use JavaScript on your project?

Comment: @naota Yes, I am using JavaScript.

Comment: you could manage all that yourself, but i would choose a framework for it. Search twitter-bootstrap , or search twitter-bootstrap alternatives via google.Goodluck.

Comment: The best way would be detecting device on server-side to decide which view to render. There are many API's available.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use JavaScript (and jQuery ), you can manage to load the content based on the width of the devise. The basic idea is something like this:

index.html

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
      <!-- content will be loaded here based on the width of the devise -->
  </div>
</body>
```

phone.html

```
 <div>
      This file is for small devices
 </div>
```

pc.html:

```
 <div>
      This file is for large devices
 </div>
```

JavaScript in index.html:

```
function loadcontent(){
   var BreakPoint = 480; // pixcel

   if($(window).width() < BreakPoint){
       file = "phone.html";
   }else{
       file = "pc.html";
   }
   $("#content").load(file);
}

loadcontent();

$(window).resize(function () {
    ....
    loadcontent();
    ....
});
```

The above code is just the basic concept. 
To handle the `window.resize` events smoothly, there are several functions to be implemented. If you would like to see the codes of that part, I will update my answer.

hope this helps.